# Family of cutoff functions

Tags: real-analysis

I want a family of smooth cutoff functions that satisfy the following:

- $\psi_k:[0, \infty)\to [0, 1]$ (for all positive integers $k>4$)
- $\psi_k([0, k])= 0 $
- $\psi_k'(2k)>k$
- $\psi_{k+1}(t)\leq \psi_k(t)$, for every $t$ in the domain.

Any help?

Comment: Do you know how to construct a function for the first three properties? There is nothing particularly novel in these requirements.

Comment: No, @Normal, that's why I'm asking for some help. Can you show me how can I construct a function satisfying the first three properties?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you are given a $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R,[0,1])$ function such that $f(\mathbb{R}_)={0}$ , $f([1,\infty))={1}$, and $f^\prime(\frac12)>1$.
You can find one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4365567/948485).
Then, take
$$
\psi_{k}=f\left(k\left((x-2k+\frac1{2k}\right)\right). 
$$
you find that, $\psi_k\in C^\infty(\mathbb R,[0,1])$, $\psi_k(x)=0$ for all $x\leq 2k-\frac1{2k}$, $\psi_k(x)=1$ for all $x>2k+\frac1{2k}$, and $\psi^\prime(2k)=kf^\prime(\frac12)>k.$

Since $\psi_k=0$ for $x\leq{2k-1}$, and $\psi_k=1$ for $x\geq{2k+1}$, $\psi_{k+1}=0$ on $[0,2k+1]$, therefore $\psi_{k+1}\leq \psi_k$.